# Right-align comments in vim

Tags: vim, text, programming

I'm writing C code using vim and are searching for a possibility to right-align my comments so that they all end at col 80. To give a short example:

```
int a = 80; /* initialize a */
int b = 7; /* initialize b */
printf("%d + %d = %d", a, b, a+b); /*calculate the result */
```

should turn into

```
int a = 80;                               /* initialize a */
int b = 7;                                /* initialize b */
printf("%d + %d = %d", a, b, a+b); /*calculate the result */
                                                           ^col 80
```

I have installed `vim-easy-align` to do other formattings but did not find out yet how to perform this alignment. Maybe someone knows how?

I do not insist on `vim-easy-align`. If you have another plugin that does the job.. Just tell me ;).

Answer (score 7):

Here is how to do it with plain vim commands, no plugins used:

In normal mode, place your cursor at the first character of the string you want to right-align, like the comment delimiter, and then press <kbd>leader</kbd> then <kbd>tab</kbd> to right align the text.

```
nnoremap <leader><tab> mc80A <esc>080lDgelD`cP
```

With explainations:

```
mc80A <esc>080lDgelD`cP
| |        |   ||  ||
mc|        |   ||  ||    Mark the position of the cursor
  |        |   ||  ||
  80A <esc>|   ||  ||    Append 80 spaces at the end
           |   ||  ||
           080l||  ||    Go the the 80th column from the beginning of the line
               ||  ||
               D|  ||    Delete what is next
                |  ||
                gel||    goes after the last string char
                   ||
                   D|    Delete the characters remaining (complement to go 80)
                    |
                    `cP  and paste these to shift the string up to 80 column.
```

To mark multiple comments, you can search the next occurence of a comment delimiter and press <kbd>leader</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>leader</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>leader</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>...

Comment: This is why I love Vim.

Answer (score 4):

My [AlignFromCursor plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4155) provides a `<Leader>ri` mapping and `:RightAlignFromCursor` command which do that. Just place the cursor in the whitespace before the comment (either manually or via a `:[range]normal` command) and invoke the mapping or command. It uses `'textwidth'` or a prefixed `[count]`.